# Problem with math operations in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var a = 3;
var x = 275.15 * a;
var z = 298.15 * a;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x, z;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to return both x and z, but it seems like this code only returns x. What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 4):

You're using the comma operator here: `.innerHTML = x, z;`. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works like this: It evaluates its left-hand operand, throws away the result, then evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. So what you have there is equivalent to `.innerHTML = z` (since `x` has no side effects). If you want to show both, use string concatenation (`.innerHTML = String(x) + ", " + z;`), or a template literal (`` .innerHTML = `${x}, ${z}`; ``), or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var a = 3;
  var x = 2 * a;
  var z = 9 * a;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (x +","+ z);
</script>
```

it's not a problem with math operators,hope this will help u